# Passing Elements (SVG) to web worker

Tags: javascript, svg, web-worker

I have this website where I need to be able to take "snapshots" of an animated SVG at different stages of its animation (slow process). In parallel, the animation is running (fast process). So I'm creating a clone and in the background I'm serializing the SVG at different animation stages and uploading the resulting images to a server.

However, all this being ran in the background is quite slow and tends to slow down the animation of the original SVG. Is it possible to do all this in a web worker? If necessary, the worker can fetch the SVG source file by itself.

I already know that passing a DOM element isn't possible:

```
//main.js
var s = new XMLSerializer();
worker.postMessage(s.serializeToString(svg))

//worker.js
parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString(e.data, "text/html");

//ERROR
Uncaught ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined
```

And it seems that just passing an object isn't an option either:

```
//main.js
worker.postMessage(JSON.stringify(svg))

//worker.js
svgObject = JSON.parse(e.data);
console.log(svgObject)

//console output (just an empty Object prototype)
Object {}
```

Is the web worker option worth pursuing, knowing that I will need things like:

- `XMLSerializer` (since the DOMParser isn't available, I don't know about that one)
- `document.createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE, 'text')` (I need to create elements within the SVG)
- `var img = new Image(); img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + svgString` (I need to create an image to capture the serialized version of the SVG)
- `element.style.strokeDashoffset = 0` (I need to be able to style the SVG)
- `SVGPolylineElement.prototype.getTotalLength` (I have a couple polyfills on SVG type prototypes to do my math, but this could always be turned into functions)

Comment: You can't use web workers for touching the DOM, which is what sounds like is slowing your animation. If it's not critical to capture it *while* it's happening, do it off-screen during idle time and capture your snapshots there. That way you avoid having to actually draw the SVG which is usually the expensive part.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes it's absolutely not necessary to capture it while it's happening. The animation ends way before the snapshots are all taken anyway! But the website is about browsing such animations, so I never know when there will be idle time or for how long. Hence the idea of using web workers.

Comment: @JaredSmith Right now, it's done on a clone that's never actually added to the DOM, then serialized and used as a `src` for an `<img>` never added to the DOM either, copied onto a `canvas` (again, off the DOM) and then uploaded to a server.

Comment: Only other perf advice I'd give you is to ensure that you queue up those tasks rather than letting them run sequentially via something on the order of `setTimeout(task, 0);`. That will at least ensure that the individual tasks are the only blocking rather than the entire pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling the JavaScript directive 'use strict' in your code, in which case you will simply need declare your "parser" variable with "var":

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
```

PS. Thanks, your code helped with my own browser extension....

Comment: I'm definitely not calling 'use strict'. I never do. I like messy code :) Has that worked for you then?

Comment: When you JavaScript's DOMParser API without 'use strict', this is what normally cause the ReferenceError  `Uncaught ReferenceError: DOMParser is not defined`.  (PS I too like messy code, but 'use strict' removes many time-bombs - my young coder :)